# Where to put a timer that updates a Redux store?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, game-development

I'm building a game and there's a score which updates every 5 sec with a timer.

Currently the score lives in a nested Component's state, but I'd like to make it available to other Components as well so it can affect their states (eg. higher score would affect the whole game's background color, the counters on top, and trigger pop-up messages).

I have Redux stores, and it feels like the right place for this score, but which component should be responsible for updating it/have the timer running?

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't matter. Since we need to use setInterval for the timer, it can be placed anywhere in your app(as.. from any place it will work same because of the setInterval working mechanism).
But for better code/logical understanding, I would use the same component/method which I am using to start the game for starting the interval.

Answer (score 0):

make a redux folder in which you'll have store.js file and your counterSclice.js files and here you put your update to count inside reducer.